# store a file in an array word by word

Tags: c#

i am tring to make a C# code to read from a notepad file, so how to store it in an array word by word or how to make it read and stop at a certain special mark?
for example
read$ from$ file$
and it should be stored in the array as
read
from
file

Comment: Does every wod ends with `$`?

Comment: Why didn't you use the end line character?

Comment: Very confusing question, do you want to read from a text file? There is lots of info in the web. You can start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d.aspx)

Comment: what is the end line character?

Comment: Have a look at the `string.Split()` function.

Answer (score 2):

```
File.ReadAllLines("file.txt").Split("$")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following code.

```
String[] tokens = File.ReadAllText("file.txt").Split('$');
```

tokens string array will be having you required string values.

Answer (score 0):

Save as you said. At the time of retrieving Split data with '$'. It will give you array.

```
string[] strarr = mytxtdata.Split('$');
```